# wpf adding/editing/using string values in Resources.resx

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard

I have a WPF application and i have multiple string values in Resources.resx and the access modifier of the Resources.resx is set to public.

My issue is that i want to retrieve values from the Resources.resx file directly into xml markup and also want to edit the value of the key in Resources.resx.

In order to edit some key in the Resources.resx i used

```
this.Resources["Duration_value"] = "0:0:15"; // that's a key in Resources.resx that i created
```

But it doesn't work at all, the value stays the same.

Regarding the second issue, let's say i have got a xml code for a Storyboard with doubleanimation like :

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="FlipIn" >
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(SkewTransform.AngleX)" From="-100" To="0" Duration="0:0:.75" DecelerationRatio=".9" />
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(SkewTransform.AngleY)" From="-100" To="0" Duration="0:0:.75" DecelerationRatio=".9" />
    </Storyboard>
```

Let's say i want to change the duration value on

```
Duration="0:0:.75"
```

to

```
Duration="{ Duration_value from regex file }"
```

How do i do that inside the XML markup? Like what should i type? i tried using the App.Resources but couldn't find a reference.

I am also newbie to WPF.

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Practice of changing the resource is not very good, because by default, they should be frozen. Freezing the resources used to avoid memory leaks. More information see [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509.aspx).

In some situations, it may cause an exception, for example: `InvalidOperationException`. However, the resource can be changed in code line of the form:

```
Application.Current.Resources["MyResource"] = MyNewValue;
```

**Example**

Create the `Duration` in resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Duration x:Key="MyDuration">0:0:0.75</Duration>
</Window.Resources>
```

Shown in `TextBlock` value:

```
<Grid Name="MyGrid">
    <TextBlock Name="MyTextBlock" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyDuration}}" />

    <Button Name="ChangeResource" Content="ChangeResource" Width="100" Height="30" Click="ChangeResource_Click" />
</Grid>
```

You can also use it like this:

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="MyControl" From="-100" To="0" Duration="{StaticResource MyDuration}" DecelerationRatio=".9" />
```

Listing of `ChangeResource_Click`:

```
    private void ChangeResource_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan MyTimespan = new TimeSpan(2, 2, 3);
        Duration DurationInCode = MyTimespan;

        // Set the new value
        Application.Current.Resources["MyDuration"] = MyTimespan;

        // Show value
        MyTextBlock.Text = Application.Current.Resources["MyDuration"].ToString();
    }
```

For resources that you will change, it is better to use the `DynamicResource`. See the [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748942.aspx), for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, i couldn't find Windows.Resources, by the way i am using WPF and you are using Windows forms code i guess?

Comment: No, it's WPF code. Where are you trying to look for `Window.Resources`?

Comment: i tried adding it inside app.config and it said that the namespace prefix x is not defined and my code looks like that :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <Window.Resources>
      <Duration x:Key="MyDuration">0:0:0.999</Duration>
    </Window.Resources>
</configuration>

Comment: I think you're in the wrong direction... I downloaded example, can download it from the [link](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=3FC95A33B3F2DE8A!107&authkey=!AP7ALqaGQ-OniBc).

Comment: Whenever i try to access the MyDuration value to read it, it throws a null exception , itried : MessageBox.Show(Application.Current.Resources["MyDuration"].ToString());